# Difference between `python file.py` and `python -m file`

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

In python3:

- What is the difference between calling `python path/to/file.py` and
  `python -m path.to.file` ?
- How does it affect the working directory ? ( `os.getcwd()` )
- Does it have a link with the presence / absence of an `__init__.py`
  file located in `path/to` ?

I have been surprised by how little information I found on these of questions. Maybe I am not searching with the correct terms? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the difference between calling python path/to/file.py and python -m path.to.file ?

`Python -m module_name` is a shortcut to invoking a particular module. Often this is an installed package with a `__main__.py` module inside of it. (e.g. `python -m pip` invokes `pip/__main__.py`

So `python -m pip` is equivalent to `python path/to/my/python/lib/site-packages/pip/__main__.py`

> How does it affect the working directory ? ( os.getcwd() )

It does not

> Does it have a link with the presence / absence of an **init**.py file located in path/to ?

First: There might be some confusion worth clearing up: `python -m` doesn't take a path as an argument. It takes the *name* of a module to execute.

So, short answer: no.

Long answer: how a module executed by name with `python -m` depends on whether or not it is a package. The presence of `__init__.py` can denote that the directory is the name of a package, like pip is, thusly it will look for `__main__` inside of the package.

Answer (score 2):

```
python -m ...
```

is used for running python library modules, such as pip, IPython etc.

```
python file.py
```

however is used to run files with python interpreter.